# apollo client: local state being overwritten by query?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have an app that uses:

`react-apollo`
`apollo-link-state`
`apollo-cache-persist`
`apollo-link-error`

I ran into a weird issue when I was trying to add a `pollInterval` to a query. The `pollInterval` causes an overWrite of the local cache state back to the defaults. I am not sure if this is caused directly by the pollInterval or not, but I have been troubleshooting the issue for some time with no luck.

I made a reproduction of the issue on Github here (https://github.com/deltaskelta/apollo-link-iss-573) with instructions on how to see what is happening. If anyone has any idea what is going on I would really appreciate it!

Thanks

EDIT: the full code that is causing the error is posted below

```
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";
import { ApolloProvider, graphql } from "react-apollo";
import { CachePersistor } from "apollo-cache-persist";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { onError } from "apollo-link-error";
import { withClientState } from "apollo-link-state";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    setErrors: (_, { messages }, { cache }) => {
      const data = {
        errors: {
          __typename: "Errors",
          messages
        }
      };
      cache.writeData({ data });
      return null;
    }
  }
};

// create the cache
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const persistor = new CachePersistor({
  cache,
  storage: window.localStorage,
  debug: true
});

// link to the local state cache
const stateLink = withClientState({
  cache,
  resolvers,
  defaults: {
    errors: {
      __typename: "Errors",
      messages: []
    }
  }
});

// link to intercept graphql errors and write them to the cache, this is almost like a
// middleware
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  var messages = []; // make a place to push all errors to

  // go through the network errors and graphql errors, push them to the errors array and
  // then write those errors to the cache
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, path }) => {
      messages.push(`Error: msg: ${message},  path: ${path}`);
    });
  }

  if (networkError) {
    messages.push(`Error: network: ${networkError}`);
  }

  const data = {
    errors: {
      __typename: "Errors",
      messages
    }
  };

  cache.writeData({ data });
});

// put both links in the frontend apollo client
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: ApolloLink.from([stateLink, errorLink]),
  connectToDevTools: true
});

client.onResetStore(stateLink.writeDefaults);

class Persistor extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.object,
    persistor: PropTypes.object
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.persistor.restore().then(() => {
      console.log("restored");
    });
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Persistor persistor={persistor}>
          <Errors />
        </Persistor>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}

const RootComponent = ({ errors }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello World
      {errors.map(e => <div>{e}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
};

RootComponent.propTypes = {
  errors: PropTypes.array
};

const Errors = graphql(
  gql`
    query GetErrors {
      errors @client {
        messages
      }
    }
  `,
  {
    props: ({ data }) => ({ errors: data.errors.messages }),
    options: {
      pollInterval: 1000 * 10
    }
  }
)(RootComponent);

export default App;

// TODO:
//
// - cause an error that is written to the cache
// - make a query to poll the error
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. A link to github is inadequate as any changes there will make your question and the answers useless. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: ok I posted the code into the question

Comment: Is that a [mcve]? emphasis on **minimal**.

Comment: yes, it needs multiple components and constructors to setup, that is why I initially did it all in a repo

Comment: Did you resolve this ?  I am running into the exact same issue.  Not convinced it is not just something I am doing wrong on my side but again I have a polling query that ultimately keeps taking my local state back to defaults.